# XAML trigger as StaticResource

Tags: wpf, xaml, triggers

Why can't I create a trigger and use it as a static resource in XAML?

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Trigger x:Key="ValidationTrigger" x:Shared="False" Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
        <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.ToolTip"
                Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self},
                Path=(Validation.Errors)/ErrorContent}"/>
    </Trigger>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <StaticResource ResourceKey="ValidationTrigger"/>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

I get an errormessage at runtime
"Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: triggerBase  Error at object 'System.Windows.Markup.StaticResourceHolder' in markup file"

Comment: Good question :) I would like to know the answer to this one.

Comment: As the error states: the initliazation for the resource dictionary is trying to pass null as a value for a parameter. Since trigger has a parameterless constructor I think the error stems from the binding you are trying to use.

How does RelativeSource.Self resolve in this specific use case?

Answer (score 1):

I imagine that this is because resources are loaded first.

So in this case, WPF would try to load your trigger before any control it might be associated with. Then the trigger value can't be evaluated at that time.

But that need to be confirmed :)